# Is there any way to get Gmail message sizes in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I currently have a python script that uses IMAP to get the size of every message in my Gmail account and present that info in various useful ways, such as broken down by sender. I'd like to write a Google Apps Script that does the same thing, but I'm having some trouble.

I can't find any easy way to get the size of messages in Gmail from a script. I see that I can call `getRawContent()`, and I assume that the length of that string plus the size of the message attachments should be enough information to figure out the message size. However, `getRawContent()` presumably counts as a read, and there is a quota limit of 20,000 reads per day. At that rate, it'd take several days to find the size of all the messages in my inbox! (My current IMAP technique only takes a few minutes.)

Is there any way to get the size of a message without reading the full content of the message and using up the read quota?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using following code you can get messages size as well as Attachment size
I used Gmail Advance services and GmailApps

```
    function getMsgSize() {
  var msgSizeCount = 0,
    attaSize = 0;
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in all has:attachment -in:chats AND After:2016/09/20 ')
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var msgId = threads[i].getId();
    var msgSize = Gmail.Users.Messages.get("CurrentUserEmailID", msgId).sizeEstimate;
    msgSizeCount = msgSizeCount + msgSize
    var attachemt = GmailApp.getMessageById(msgId).getAttachments()
    if (attachemt) {
      for (var j = 0; j < attachemt.length; j++) {
        attaSize = attaSize + attachemt[j].getSize()
      }
    }
  }
  Logger.log(['Message Size: ' + msgSize / 1024 + 'MB', 'Attachment Size: ' + attaSize / 1024 + 'MB'])
}
```

Using this code you can customize your input messages 
or  you can use

1) **Gmail Message Size**:  var msgSize=Gmail.Users.Messages.get("CurrentUserEmailID", msgId).sizeEstimate;

**For Attachment size** : var attachemt=GmailApp.getMessageById(msgId).getAttachments() 
    if(attachemt){
     for(var j=0;j

You can use above methods.
Output :[image]

Comment: The answer is something like this, with the caveat that sizeEstimate and getSize return their answer in bytes, so you have to divide by 1024^2 to get MB. I'm not sure why you have to consider attachment size separately, since the docs strongly imply that the message size includes attachments.

Comment: Also, there's a difference between threads and messages - it might be that the thread IDs are the same as the message ID of the first message, which explains why this seems to work, but it's not actually considering the size of other messages in the thread (or attachments on other messages).

Comment: Anyway... this API is rate-limited too - this will take 30+ minutes to run on all mail, and will require checking for "quota exceeded" error messages (or simply limiting rate conservatively), as well as splitting the task into multiple runs (since Apps Script execution is limited to 4 minutes). It's still much faster and easier to just do this over IMAP.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the "**[Advanced Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/gmail)**"

> The Advanced Gmail service allows you to use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api) in Apps Script. Much like Apps Script's [built-in Gmail service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail), this API allows scripts to find and modify threads, messages, and labels in a Gmail mailbox. In most cases, the built-in service is easier to use, but this advanced service provides a few extra features and access to more detailed information about Gmail content.

I haven't tried this but the documentation said :

> For detailed information on this service, see the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/) for the Gmail API. Like all advanced services in Apps Script, the advanced Gmail service uses the same objects, methods, and parameters as the public API.

Using this will make it possible to get the [sizeEstimate](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) (for message) and [size](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/attachments#resource) (for attachment).

Hope it helps!